# How to use a variable as an int inside a query to a mssql db using qt?

Tags: sql, qt, qtsql

I have built a quick app I'm trying to make to learn how I could implement dynamic fitment or category options list to a list of products(I.E. Make, Model, Year Search). I thought I found a simple way of doing this, but I have found it is harder than Ithought. I've made the combo boxes I need for the fitment options dynamicly but I can't figure out how to take the ID for the fitment group and use it in a new query as part of the 'where clause'. What is the best way in qt to use a variable as an int inside a query to a mssql db?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtSql>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setHostName("ROBERT-PC");
db.setDatabaseName("mydsn32");

if(!db.open())
{
    qDebug() << "Could Not Open";
}
else
{
    QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout();

    qDebug() << "Open, and now closing";
    QSqlQuery qry;

    if(qry.exec("SELECT * FROM [BOBs].[dbo].[FitmentTagGroup]"))
    {
        qDebug() << "Query Was Opened";
        while(qry.next())
        {
            QString combBoxName = qry.value(1).toString() + "CombBox";
            int combBoxID = qry.value(0).toInt();
            QLabel *combBoxNameLbl = new QLabel();
            combBoxNameLbl->setText(combBoxName);
            QComboBox *combBox = new QComboBox();
            QSqlQuery qry2;
            if(qry2.exec("SELECT * FROM [BOBs].[dbo].[FitmentTag] WHERE FitmentTagGroupID='1'"))
            {
                while(qry2.next())
                {
                    qDebug() << qry2.value(2).toString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                qDebug() << "Query Could Not Open\n\t" << qry2.lastError();
            }
            vbox->addWidget(combBoxNameLbl);
            vbox->addWidget(combBox);
        }
    }
    else
    {
       qDebug() << "Query Could Not Open\n\t" << qry.lastError();
    }

    model = new QSqlQueryModel();

    db.close();

    QFrame *mainFrame = new QFrame();
    mainFrame->setLayout(vbox);
    setCentralWidget(mainFrame);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use prepared statements and binding values to solve your problem.

Instead of using

```
qry2.exec(
   "SELECT * "
   "FROM [BOBs].[dbo].[FitmentTag] "
   "WHERE FitmentTagGroupID = '1' "
);
```

you should use something like this:

```
qry2.prepare(
   "SELECT * "
   "FROM [BOBs].[dbo].[FitmentTag] "
   "WHERE FitmentTagGroupID = :groupid "
);
qry2.bindValue(":groupid", groupId);
qty2.exec();
```

Read more [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qsqlquery.html#approaches-to-binding-values).

Comment: Great helps, and thanks! I thought i had to bind values but I couldn't really figure it out. I could only find examples where values where binded on insert statements, but I guess I should have put 2 & 2 together; Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Note that formatting SQL properly makes a big difference